# openid app auth custom social login giving exception ANDROID

Tags: android, openid, appauth

this is my manifest file :

```
<activity 
      android:name=".activities.LoginActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.dyafat.HANDLE_AUTHORIZATION_RESPONSE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity
        android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
        tools:node="replace">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="com.dyafat"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

this is my activity file : onclick of button i am calling this method

private static final String AUTHORIZATION_ACTION="com.dyafat.HANDLE_AUTHORIZATION_RESPONSE";

Uri authorizationEndpoint = Uri.parse("https://--my auth uri-----/authorize");

```
Uri tokenEndpoint =Uri.parse("https://---- my toekn uri ---------/token");

String clientId = "client_id";
String responseType = AuthorizationRequest.RESPONSE_TYPE_CODE;
Uri redirectUri = Uri.parse("my_uri/oauth2callback");

public void performAuthorizationRequest() {

    AuthorizationService service = new AuthorizationService(this);
    AuthorizationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
            new AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
                    authorizationEndpoint,
                    tokenEndpoint), clientId, responseType, redirectUri);

    AuthorizationRequest request = builder
            .setScope("openid profile email")
            .build();
    service.performAuthorizationRequest(request,
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    request.hashCode(),
                    new Intent(AUTHORIZATION_ACTION),
                    0));


    service.dispose();
}


@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    checkIntent(getIntent());
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    checkIntent(intent);
}

private void checkIntent( Intent intent)
{ if (intent != null)
    {
        if (Constants.Login.equals("1"))
        {
            intent.setAction(AUTHORIZATION_ACTION);
        }

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action!=null)
        {
            switch (action)
            {
                case AUTHORIZATION_ACTION:
                    if (!intent.hasExtra(USED_INTENT))
                    {
                        handleAuthorizationResponse(intent);
                        intent.putExtra(USED_INTENT, true);
                    }
                    break;
           
                default:
                    // do nothing
            }
        }

    }
}




private void handleAuthorizationResponse(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    AuthorizationResponse response = AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(intent);
    AuthorizationException error = AuthorizationException.fromIntent(intent);

    if (response != null)
    {
        final AuthState authState = new AuthState(response, error);
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", String.format("Handled Authorization Response %s ", authState.toString()));
        AuthorizationService service = new AuthorizationService(this);
        service.performTokenRequest(response.createTokenExchangeRequest(), new AuthorizationService.TokenResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTokenRequestCompleted(@Nullable TokenResponse tokenResponse, @Nullable AuthorizationException exception) {
                if (exception != null) {
                    Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Token Exchange failed "+ exception);
                } else {
                    if (tokenResponse != null)
                    {
                        accessToken=tokenResponse.accessToken;
                        Log.e("LOG_TAG", String.format("Token Response [ Access Token: %s, ID Token: %s ]", tokenResponse.accessToken, tokenResponse.idToken));

                        authState.update(tokenResponse, exception);

                       // persistAuthState(authState);
                       // Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Token Response [ Access Token: %s, ID Token: %s ]", tokenResponse.accessToken, tokenResponse.idToken));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error what i am getting :

2020-08-11 21:10:48.255 15269-15269/com.google.codelabs.appauth W/AppAuthSample: Token Exchange failed
AuthorizationException: {"type":0,"code":3,"errorDescription":"Network error"}
at net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask.doInBackground(AuthorizationService.java:244)
at net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask.doInBackground(AuthorizationService.java:206)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://----- MY -TOKEN URL ------/connect/token
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source:0)
at net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask.doInBackground(AuthorizationService.java:239)

Comment: please explain the question if you want use to help you, follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ...

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use an absolute URL here:

```
Uri redirectUri = Uri.parse("my_uri/oauth2callback");
```

See this question

- [Why is the redirect_uri defined to be an absolute uri in OAuth2?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/149782/why-is-the-redirect-uri-defined-to-be-an-absolute-uri-in-oauth2)